# iOS Push notification sending error

Tags: php, ios, ssl, openssl, push-notification

I am an iOS app developer and don't know much about php. I am following [raywenderlich push notification tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) to generate an SSL certificates and private key for push notification.

I followed the steps 3-4 times but it does not work. I had followed the same steps previously and it worked.

I think the issue is in the response I get when I test connecting to APNS server using SSL certificate. I am getting below response.

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./OU=iTMS Engineering/CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
   i:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
 1 s:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
   i:/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./OU=iTMS Engineering/CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2731 bytes and written 2177 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 0E813189A9AA0F93F3C996DB3D80240F742EB24656AEED9DC18043DCEDD854E9B1C4798098312EB7F6CAB23B10FF343C
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1393333259
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

In beginning of response it gives error `verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate`. In later part of response also it says `No client certificate CA names sent`.
I am not aware these things, but I suspect the problem is with these errors.

**EDIT :** Error I get while sending notification using sample php script provided in tutorial.

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file `/Users/akashpatel/Desktop/SimplePush/ck.pem' in /Users/akashpatel/Desktop/SimplePush/simplepush.php on line 25

Warning: stream_socket_client(): failed to create an SSL handle in /Users/akashpatel/Desktop/SimplePush/simplepush.php on line 25

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /Users/akashpatel/Desktop/SimplePush/simplepush.php on line 25

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /Users/akashpatel/Desktop/SimplePush/simplepush.php on line 25
Failed to connect: 0
```

**EDIT :** 
**Using this [app](https://github.com/blommegard/APNS-Pusher) (suggested by segev in his answer) I tested whether any issue with certificate/private key. I could receive a notification successfully. So I guess problem is not with certificate/private key.**

**PHP Script I am using :**

```
<?php

$deviceToken = 'r34f34f5g45g5y56u76hj676elfjn4urno43f958gh945g8g7';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = ‘pasphrase’;

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Received push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

**EDIT :** My script works when I use it in production server. But I will keep this question open as it is not working in local server. Suggestions might help others for whom its not working in production server.

Comment: What is your ssl command? Have you tried: openssl s_client -connect host:443 -cert cert_and_key.pem -key cert_and_key.pem  -state -debug

Comment: @Radu cert_and_key.pem is specified twice in your command. Is it correct or a mistake? I use the command `openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert Cert.pem -key Key.pem`.

Comment: @Radu I tried changing port to `443` and got error. `connect: Connection refused, connect:errno=61`.

Comment: What is the error you receive when trying to push a message to your device?

Comment: @Radu I haven't try to do that because even this is not working. I tried sending notification using php script that the tutorial provides. I'll post error I get while doing that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48430/discussion-between-geek-and-radu)

Comment: @Geek did you find any feasible solution for testing in the Development mode as I am getting the same issue, working on production mode but not in development mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what was the problem when I tested using PHP script provided by the tutorial I followed on local server. But when I tested using production server then it was sending notifications.

Answer (score 4):

There are so many things that go wrong with Push Notification that you'll need to approach them one by one.

Forget about the php code for a second. 
Go [here](https://github.com/blommegard/APNS-Pusher/releases) and download the latest release.

This is a great tiny app that does all the server side for you and will send a push notification to your device. If that works you can go on and implement the php code but I suspect that your problem lies with the app certificate \ key.

Comment: I downloaded the app and sent a notification using the same certificate. I received a notification. Now it means certificate and key are fine. What can be other issues? BTW thanks and +1 for the link to app. At least I know that I don't need to create them again to see if problem was with them.

Answer (score 3):

See the error:

> CONNECTED(00000003) depth=1 /C=US/O=Entrust,
>   Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009
>   Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C verify
>   error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate verify return:0

Look how you set applied the context to stream option:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
```

I used the same tutorial as you, on the troobleshooting section read the bullet #3

> Unable to get local issuer certificate. This error means that the
>   certificate from the server could not be verified. To fix this you
>   need to download the Entrust CA root certificate. This can be done
>   from the Terminal using the command: curl -O
>   https://www.entrust.net/downloads/binary/entrust_2048_ca.cer You then
>   also need to add stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile',
>   'entrust_2048_ca.cer');

Download [entrust_2048_ca.cer](https://mega.co.nz/#!PIAQwagA!KAkRnfHf2KN5uQVxsRC0R3wGsjvLhw9ukf02LTQh5DY)

make sure all your cerificate are in the same directory as the PHP script.

Change your code to the following:

```
//applying context to stream option
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');
```

You should be good now.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my question. I already tried that. But not working.

Comment: are you available to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48430/discussion-between-geek-and-radu)

Comment: @Geek any feedback on that attempt ?

Comment: It did not work. I gave feedback in chat. I thought writing in chat conversation will give you notify you..

Comment: Not getting what is that. Which key and id they are asking?